# Extract and recreate DDL of database schema elsewhere

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I guess I just cannot formulate the search query appropriately, but I cannot find an answer to the following simple question: *how to use extracted DDL pieces to recreate tables, views etc. in a different database or a different schema?*

For example, when I extract table DDL with

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl ('TABLE', TABLE-NAME, SCHEMA) FROM dual
```

I get output with `FOREIGN KEY` there.  If I now naively issue the resulting `CREATE TABLE` statements on a different database in e.g. alphabetical order of table names, I get "table or view doesn't exist" error, because constraints reference to non-yet-created tables.

What is the normal procedure of using DDL?  Is it (easily) possible to recreate full scheme structure (short of full database dump) without using external tools?

Comment: `expdp` lets you do a schema export, or even specific tables, and `impdp` would handle the constraints/dependencies for you - which isn't a full dump, but you'd still cont that as an external tool? Even over a network link, if you're allowed those? (There's also [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/metadata_api.htm#SUTIL1629) but you have the same issue about finding the order to create the objects, and/or creating the objects without constraints and adding them on top later).

Comment: I actually didn't realize that it's possible to use `expdp` only for metadata, i.e. structure without contents. However, it generates a binary file. I assume it's not possible to make it generate PL/SQL instead?

Comment: I don't think it can generate DDL as part of the export, but once you have the .dmp file [`impdp` can via its SQLFILE option](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL933). Or while doing an actual import you can do various transformations (schema, tablespaces, even object names). SQL Developer (and other external tools) can generate the DDL; not sure if that lists the objects in a dependency-friendly way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [datapump export CONTENT option](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL838) to only export the metadata for a schema:

> CONTENT=[ALL | DATA_ONLY | METADATA_ONLY]
>
> - ALL unloads both data and metadata. This is the default.
> - DATA_ONLY unloads only table row data; no database object definitions are unloaded.
> - METADATA_ONLY unloads only database object definitions; no table row data is unloaded. Be aware that if you specify CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY, then when the dump file is subsequently imported, any index or table statistics imported from the dump file will be locked after the import.

The import process will create the objects and constraints, taking the dependencies into account.

If you want to see the DDL, and optionally run it manually, you can use [the datapump import SQLFILE option](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL933) to put the DDL into a file instead of executing it:

> Specifies a file into which all of the SQL DDL that Import would have executed, based on other parameters, is written.

You can do similar things through SQL Developer and other clients, but those are 'external tools', whereas datapump might not fall into that category, even if you have to run it from the command line. There is [a datapump API](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_api.htm#SUTIL600) so you can even avoid the command line if you want to, though in some ways it's more complicated than using the `expdp` and `impdp` utilities.